# How can I send command to AirFlow which is published on remote machine

Tags: airflow

1. I have a AirFlow service running normally on remote machine, which can be accessed through Browser with URL: http://airflow.xxx.com
2. Now I want to dynamically upload DAGs from **another machine** to AirFlow at airflow.xxx.com, and make that DAG auto run.

After I read the airflow document: http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/, I found way to dynamically create DAGs and auto run it, which can be done on the airflow machine airflow.xxx.com.

But I want to do it in another machine, how can I accomplish it, is there a way like webhdfs, which let me directly send command to remote AirFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your new dag in the Apache Airflow dag directory.

If you didn't set Airflow up in a cluster environment, you should have web-server, scheduler and worker all running on the same machine.
On that machine, if you did not amend airflow.cfg, you should have your dag directory in `dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags`

If you access the Airflow machine from the other machine through SFTP (or FTP) you can simply put the file in that dir.